# Java reading formatted text file and dividing it

Tags: java, file-io, text-files, fileinputstream

I'm trying to understand file I/O for class and I understand the basics but I'm having trouble understanding how to manage whats in the input file, the input file is formatted like this:

> BusinessContact:firstName=Nikolaos;lastName=Tsantalis
>   SocialNetworkAccount:socialNetworkType=SKYPE;accountID=tsantalis

Basically my contact (which BusinessContact extends from) object has attributes of firstName, lastName and middleName,
it also has object attributes such as SocialNetworkAccount and such....

I don't need to be explained how my objects are formatted, those have been done all I'm trying to understand is how my file.txt in inputed into my program to set my Contact to a BusinessContact as well as setting the first and last name accordingly,

Thanks

EDIT: Im specifically told to use the split method which makes sense but I'm also told (1) create a common method for the parsing of attributes that returns a map where the keys correspond to the attributeNames and the values to the attributeValues (in this way you can reuse the same code)

Comment: I suspect you'll have to parse the file, pull out the stuff you need, instantiate classes from strings and fill in the fields. Does not sound pleasant to me.

Comment: Every line is formatted like `[label]:([key]=[value])(;[key]:[value])...`

Comment: makes sense but there has to be a reason that the text file specifically says "firstName=Nikolaos" , as in i have a attribute of type String called firstName and that line somehow sets it... its so confusing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Scanner` class with different delimiters like below:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(/**source*/);

in.useDelimiter(":");

String firstName, lastName;

String firstWord = in.next();

Scanner nameScanner = new Scanner(in.nextLine());

nameScanner.useDelimiter(";");

firstName = getName(new Scanner(nameScanner.next()));

lastName = getName(new Scanner(nameScanner.next()));


private String getName(Scanner nameScanner){
    nameScanner.useDelimiter("=");

    String nameTitle = nameScanner.next();

    return nameScanner.next();
}
```

This way you read the text in parts as follows as follows:

`BusinessContact`**:**`firstName=Nikolaos;lastName=Tsantalis` 
                                                 `firstName=Nikolaos`**;**`lastName=Tsantalis`
                                                 `firstName`**=**`Nikolaos`;`lastName`**=**`Tsantalis`

I hope this makes sense.

NOTE: This code reads only the first line. If you want to read the second i guess its not hard to modify it. If you want the second line too or if you have any issues let me know and i will update the answer.

**EDIT**: I just noticed that every line is formated the same way so basically you can use the same code for every line. Maybe in a loop like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(/**source*/);

while(input.hasNextLine()){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
    ...
    ....
    //The above code
}
```

**String.split()** method:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] first = in.nextLine().split(":");
String[] second = first[1].split(";");
String[] thirdA = second[0].split("=");
String[] thirdB = second[1].split("=");

for(int i = 0; i < thirdA.length; i++){
    System.out.println(thirdA[i]);
    System.out.println(thirdB[i]);
}
```

For the first line, the above code will print:

```
firstName
lastName
Nikolaos
Tsantalis
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that makes sense however i must use the Split method instead of the useDelimiter and I'm instructed to create a common method for the parsing of attributes that returns a map where the keys correspond to the attributeNames and the values to the attributeValues (in this way you can reuse the same code)

Comment: Well, either using `Scanner` or `String.split()` the logic is the same pretty much. 1) Read line by line 2) Split at `:` 3)split at `;` 4) split at `=`. Pack it all in a method or two, store values accordingly and return them.

Comment: Note that when you use `String.split()` you get back an `Array` so when you want to split further you have to access the desired index.

Comment: alright i understand, that makes sense however upon going further i noticed i have a line with a middleName attribute

>BusinessContact:firstName=Marios;middleName=E.;lastName=Fokaefs

how would i make an exception to this and make the previous middle names null

Comment: Well you can add some logic that checks how many items are there with `;` as delimiter. Or if you are using `String.split()` count the number of elements in the array. And if `2` set the middle name variable to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, but you might feel more comfortable with String.split: Split on ":" and get the label, the split the second part on ";" to get the attributes, then split each attribute on "=" to get the key and the value.

Comment: yeah i'm specifically told to use the split method but I'm also told the following: (1) create a common method for the parsing of attributes that returns a map where the keys correspond to the attributeNames and the values to the attributeValues (in this way you can reuse the same code)

Comment: It's your homework, not mine. And it is a fairly straightforward exercise.